# Mean by row of a dataframe with a column containing a string of numbers separated by commas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF containing a column with numbers separated by commas (it's a string field).

I need to calculate the mean by row of every value contained in that column.

Example:

```
"COLUMN 1"
2,18,10
10
80,20
```

Expected result:

```
"MEAN"
10
10
50
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the comma separated string into list then convert list of string to multiple columns and last calculate the mean along columns.

```py
df['Mean'] = (pd.DataFrame(df['COLUMN 1'].str.split(',').tolist())
              .astype('float').mean(axis=1))
# or
df['Mean'] = (df['COLUMN 1'].str.split(',')
              .apply(pd.Series).astype('float').mean(axis=1))
```

```
  COLUMN 1  Mean
0  2,18,10  10.0
1       10  10.0
2    80,20  50.0
```